# Scrollbar is throwing off my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem with this design. The page is supposed to start with an image that is focused in the middle of the viewport, then you scroll down below the fold to see more content. I have it working with the code below but there's one issue. The scrollbar throws the viewport image off center. Does anyone know how to fix this? keep in mind, I still want the scrollbar there.

I don't know if this is possible. But could I use jquery to subtract the scrollbar width from the site only if scrollbar is active? I don't really know how to use jquery though. And I feel that if I subtract scrollbar width from 100vw then the site will look off on mobile when there is no scrollbar.

```css
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
min-height: 100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

#abovefoldcontainer {
background-color: red;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}

#abovefoldimage {
background-color: #6FF;
position: relative;
left: 150px;
top:  150px;
width: calc(100vw - 300px);
height:  calc(100vh - 300px);   
}

#belowfold {
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="abovefoldcontainer">
    <div id="abovefoldimage">Content goes here</div>
</div>

<div id="belowfold">
    Content goes here too<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to force the scrollbar to always be visible?

Comment: You can use `width: 100%` on `#abovefoldcontainer` and its won't go out

Comment: I changed [width: calc(100vw - 300px)] to [width: calc(100% - 300px)] and it works! Such a simple fix that I missed. Thanks!